# package.json issue while deploying a node api on Azure App Service

Tags: node.js, deployment, azure-web-app-service, github-actions

I wish to deploy a node api on Azure App Service using Github Actions. The app I wish to deploy is on a subfolder called "api" of the repository.

The Github Actions part works fine, but the website doesn't work, and when I look in the logs, it shows this error : "Error: Cannot find module '../package.json'".

The app should look for package.json in ./, I don't know why it is searching in ../ .

Here is my Github Actions yaml :

```
# Docs for the Azure Web Apps Deploy action: https://github.com/Azure/webapps-deploy
# More GitHub Actions for Azure: https://github.com/Azure/actions

name: Build and deploy Node.js app to Azure Web App - hobbeez

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
        

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Set up Node.js version
        uses: actions/setup-node@v1
        with:
          node-version: '16.x'

      - name: npm install, build, and test
        run: |
          npm install
          npm run build --if-present
        working-directory: api

      - name: Upload artifact for deployment job
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: node-app
          path: .

  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build
    environment:
      name: 'Production'
      url: ${{ steps.deploy-to-webapp.outputs.webapp-url }}

    steps:
      - name: Download artifact from build job
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: node-app

      - name: 'Deploy to Azure Web App'
        id: deploy-to-webapp
        uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
        with:
          app-name: 'hobbeez'
          slot-name: 'Production'
          publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_PUBLISHPROFILE_16C52153CB9348578BF747E038921ED6 }}
          package: .
```

I added a ".deployment" file at the root of the repository to specify that it should deploy the "api" subfolder, here is what this file contains :

```
[config]
project = api
```

I tried to search for the answer for weeks, but I didn't manage to find a solution. Does anyone have an idea of what am I doing wrong ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

- I have deployed  a node api on Azure App Service using GitHubActions
- Your source file `index.js`  or `app.js` file has to be under `src` folder
  [image]
- In `package.json`, add the start script as `index.js` or `app.js` based on your script

```cs
"start": "node src/index.js",
```

[image]

> ```ini
>  [config] 
>  project = api
> ```

Yes, the way you specified is correct to deploy a subfolder.

- Another option to deploy the contents of subfolder is by creating a new repository in the subfolder and deploy using Azure CI/CD.

> Cannot find module '../package.json

Remove the `node_modules` folder and `package-lock.json` and run `npm install` again